# spring-data-neo4j findByPropertyValue method always return null?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

i've got Social model :

```
import java.util.Set;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Fetch;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelatedTo;

@NodeEntity
public class Social {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Indexed
    private Long userId;

    @RelatedTo(type="FRIEND", direction=Direction.BOTH)
    @Fetch private Set<Social> friends;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Set<Social> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(Set<Social> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    public void addFriend(Social social){
        this.friends.add(social);
    }
}
```

and repository :

```
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.RelationshipOperationsRepository;

import com.msci.travelpad.entities.Social;

public interface SocialRepository extends GraphRepository<Social>, RelationshipOperationsRepository<Social> {

}
```

but when i would to find social node by userId using :

```
public Social findByUserId(Long userId) {
    return socialRepository.findByPropertyValue("userId", userId);
}
```

findByUserId always return null.

[image]

Comment: I ran your code without any issue. You need to post the code where you are calling the findByUserId() method.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to implement your own find method in the repository like:

```
Iterable<Social> findByUserId(Long userId);
```

Are the indexes created correctly (see [Null return using GraphRepository from Spring Data for Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966402/null-return-using-graphrepository-from-spring-data-for-neo4j))?